# Find by key and return value or null

Tags: javascript, json, lodash

To find a record by a key and return a property of it:

```
this.db('settings').find({ name : 'option1' }).value
```

But if the record doesn't exist I get an error "Cannot read property 'value' of undefined"

is there some other method that is able to return the "value" property if the record exists, or null if it doesn't exist?

Comment: `this.db('settings').find({ name : 'option1' }) ? this.db('settings').find({ name : 'option1' }).value : null;`

Comment: ok i was just wondering if lodash or lowdb provide some convenience function for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.db('settings').find({name: 'option1'}, function(err, result){
    if(err){console.log(err)}

    if(result){
        // do stuff 
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could store the result in a variable and use a ternary operator (assuming your code snippet is part of a function):

```
var result = this.db('settings').find({ name : 'option1' });
return result ? result.value : null;
```